# center thumbs in splidejs image gallery

Tags: javascript, splidejs

I am working on a Thumbnail Slider like here:

https://splidejs.com/tutorials/thumbnail-slider/

on big screens the thumbs are left aligned.
I tried to center them.

see https://codepen.io/caplod/pen/ExboPyP

but then the first one gets cut off on small screens.

```
#thumb .splide__list {
  justify-content: center
}
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add code align-items:center;

```
#thumb .splide__list {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```